# Header navbar too bulky

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, navbar

I am working on this site - http://galleriadesigns.co.uk/dev/

The problem I have is that the Nav-Bar is to bulky. Any ideas on how I can make it smaller, while keeping the same layout.

I tried changing the (top and z-index properties), this just pushed everything up and doesn't look good.

I want it similar to this - https://www.cxwebexperts.com/themes/adam/

This is my CSS -

```
.intelligent-header {
transition: .3s;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
z-index: 999;
transform: translateY(0%);
top: 0;
border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
```

}

```
body.logged-in.admin-bar .intelligent-header { top: 32px; –}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You're asking us to do the work for you. Please provide code and ask a proper question.

Comment: body.logged-in.admin-bar .intelligent-header {
    top: 32px;

Answer (score 0):

If you wonder why your question is being downvoted, have a look a these guidelines: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

As you want to achieve a similar aspect than the Adam's theme demo, you might wan't to crop your logo, which is causing the menu to be way bigger than in the demo's website, just compare their size :

- Your image is 60 pixels tall
- Adam's logo is 30 pixels tall

You might wan't to try to reduce the height of your logo, cropping the top and bottom margins for starters.

If you want to go further and modify the theme's css, you could remove `padding` for the `.logo` class, or set it to 0 for that matter, but it might cause other design *bulkiness*.

Answer (score 0):

For your `.logo` class you have your padding as the following: `padding: 25px 0px;`

:

```
.logo {
    padding: 8px 0;
    transition: .3s;
}
```

DECREASE the `padding` (for top & bottom i.e. `25px` down to `10px;`)

Answer (score 0):

As per your website link, I have found some issue with CSS.
here I am sending CSS for that

`.logo {padding: 15px 0;}
.logo .navbar-brand > img {width: 55px; margin: 0;}
.header-middle-area #menu-primary-menu.main-menu.hover-style-one.clearfix {margin: 0;}`